# DateTime parameter issue

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2008

I tested this method for the string parameter alone, and it worked perfectly. So I am sure there is a mistake in setting up the parameter of type DateTime (datapubl), which I added later. Thank you in advance!

By the way, the CatalogCreateFilmsTest sproc was executed and works OK.

Anna

```
public static bool CreateFilmTest(string nume, string datapubl)
        {
            DbCommand com = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();
            com.CommandText = "CatalogCreateFilmTest";

            DbParameter param = com.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@nume";
            param.Value = nume;
            param.DbType = DbType.String;
            param.Size = 200;
            com.Parameters.Add(param);

            param = com.CreateParameter();
            param.ParameterName = "@datapubl";
            param.Value = datapubl;
            param.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
            com.Parameters.Add(param);


            int result = -1;

            try
            {
                result = GenericDataAccess.ExecuteNonQuery(com);

            }
            catch
            {
                // 
            }

            return (result >= 1);

        }
```

EDIT: The problem is the stored procedure is not even executed (it should insert rows into a table  but doesn't) . No error, but not the correct result either.

EDIT: Chris, here is the full example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CatalogCreateFilmTest(
@nume nvarchar(1500),
@datapubl datetime
)
AS
INSERT INTO Filme
(nume, datapubl) 
VALUES
(@nume, @datapubl)
;
GO
```

which works for:

```
EXEC CatalogCreateFilmTest 'achu', '';
```

I then call CreateFilmTest like this:

```
bool success = FilmsAccess.CreateFilmTest(newNume.Text, null);
```

or:

```
bool success = FilmsAccess.CreateFilmTest(newNume.Text, DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

In both cases, the ExecuteNonQuery doesn't run.

Comment: What is exception? What is the problem?

Comment: Remove the try/catch block (that's a bad technique) and please explain exactly what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is the stored procedure is not even executed.

Comment: To further diagnose your issue, I'd have to see the stored proc and what values you're passing into the proc.

Comment: Could it be something as simple as setting `com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure`? You say that the `ExecuteNonQuery` doesn't run. Do you mean that the line of code isn't executed? Or that the query is run but doesn't do anything? Also, if the data type in SQL is `DateTime`, then you probably don't want to pass a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe you can reuse the same variable due to the reference in the collection...

```
        DbParameter param1 = com.CreateParameter(); 
        param1.ParameterName = "@nume"; 
        param1.Value = nume; 
        param1.DbType = DbType.String; 
        param1.Size = 200; 
        com.Parameters.Add(param1); 


        DbParameter param2 = com.CreateParameter(); 
        param2.ParameterName = "@datapubl"; 
        param2.Value = datapubl; 
        param2.DbType = DbType.DateTime; 
        com.Parameters.Add(param2);
```

Also note, that you can use syntax like so with .net 4 (and maybe 3.5 too).

```
com.Parameters.Add(
  com.CreateParameter()
  { 
    ParameterName = "@datapubl", 
    Value = datapubl, 
    DbType = DbType.DateTime
  }
);
```

It also might help to know what the exception is by filling in your catch block:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{ 
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message); 
}
```

EDIT:

I believe I see the issue now... (and should have seen it before).

Change your method signature to:

```
public static bool CreateFilmTest(string nume, DateTime datapubl)
```

And try executing the following:

```
bool success = FilmsAccess.CreateFilmTest(newNume.Text, DateTime.Now);
```

To pass null, you'll have to pass `Convert.DbNull` provided your column allows null.

In order to pass strings as DateTime values, you'll have to format them a specific way, i.e. YYYYMMDD however, I recommend letting the underlying DbCommand object take care of that.

Comment: Thank you Chris! I must say that I've been reusing the same variable for parameters in the past similarly and it works. I still think this is related to handling /setting a special type parameter (date type). I added the specifics in the initial question and requested. Good day.

Comment: +1 for the edit at the end - it's treating datetimes as strings that gets people *into* these kind of messes.

Comment: @AnnaT - You should also apply @PhaDaPhunk's answer, and change the `CommandType` of your `com` object.

Answer (score 2):

You really should add this line :

```
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Is it possible that your DateTime is empty when you pass it ?

If it is you should test to make sure it's not and if it is, pass it like this :

```
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datapubl, emptyDate == null ? DBNull.Value : (object)emptyDate);
```

Im sure this is the problem.

Hope this will help.

### EDIT :

Replace this whole block :

```
        param = com.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@datapubl";
        param.Value = datapubl;
        param.DbType = DbType.DateTime;
        com.Parameters.Add(param);
```

By something like this :

```
       if(Date is null)
       {
         com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datapubl", emptyDate == null ? DBNull.Value (object)emptyDate);
       }
       else
       {
         com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datapubl", [Your Date Variable Here]);
       }
```

Comment: In your exemple you Exec with an empty Date " ".

Comment: Thanks very much, PhaDaPhunk, I did add the com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  line - but inside GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand(), which method definition I didn't include here for simplicity, but **great** idea! As for your second suggestion, it sounds interesting but I was unsure exactly **where to place** that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know how it works for you:

```
    param = new DBParameter("@datapubl", System.Data.DbType.DateTime);
    param.Value = datapubl;
    com.Parameters.Add(param)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks nachogsiri! I can't unfortunately use this, because in my situation the parameter is specified as linked/associated with a certain command --> DbParameter param = commandx.CreateParameter(); whereas in your code, that doesn't show. So I checked the DbCommand class and I haven't found an SqLiteParameter method there.

Comment: My bad, thought you were in SQLite. Bad reading, I will modify that.